# Exponential sums over rings

Tags: nt.number-theory, exponential-sums

I'm trying to evaluate an exponential sum of the form:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{c\in Z_q}\chi(f(c))
\end{equation}
For polynomial $f(x)=a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$ (with $a_2\ne 0$).

If $q$ is prime, then this is known (appears as theorem 5.33 in *Finite Fields* by Rudolf Lidl and Niederreiter).

My question is how to evaluate this sum for non-prime $q$? (In particular for $q=p^n$ for some prime $p$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$).

Also, in general I couldn't find any literature that deals with exponential sums over rings (rather than fields), so a reference for that would also be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

These are Gauss sums modulo $n.$ Let $G(a,b,n)$ where $a,b,n$ are positive integers be given by
$$
G(a,b,n) = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}_n} \chi(ax^2 +bx)
$$
then for $a\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ with $(a,n)=1,$ one has
$$
G(a,0,n):=G(a,n)=\varepsilon_n 
\left(\frac an\right)\sqrt{n},\quad n\equiv 1\pmod 2,
$$
and
$$
G(a,0,n)=(1+i)\varepsilon_a^{-1}
\left(\frac an\right)\sqrt{n},\quad n\equiv 0\pmod4 \textrm{ and } a\equiv 1\pmod 2
$$
and $G(a,n)=0$, if $n\equiv 0 \pmod n.$ Here
$\left(\frac{\cdot}{n}\right)$ is the Jacobi symbol and $\varepsilon_n=1,$ if $n\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ while
$\varepsilon_n=i,$ if $n\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

For general $a$ modulo $n$ we have
$$
G(a,b,n)=(a,n)G\left(\frac{a}{(b,n)},
\frac{b}{(b,n)},\frac{n}{(b,n)}\right),\quad\textrm{ if } (a,n)\mid b
$$
and $G(a,b,n)=0$ otherwise. This will enable you to compute the modulus of the sum.

Also if $n$ is odd and $a\in \mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ we have
$$
G(a,b,n)=G(a,n)\chi(-b^2/4a).
$$